# Prometheus remote storage retention policy

Tags: prometheus

I have a question.

Does `--storage.tsdb.retention.time` also make sense for remote storage? Or only affects local storage?
If `--storage.tsdb.retention.time` only affects prometheus local storage, how should I limit remote storage retention?

PS: I'm using influxdb as remote storage. So I create a `retention policy` on the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `--storage.tsdb.*` should only affect local storage. The retention policy is/must be specific to the storage component because there are other strategies to handle "old" data such as downsampling.

[Prometheus agent mode](https://prometheus.io/blog/#prometheus-agent-mode) currently disables local storage so the option will not be used unless [other features](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/9607) are introduced.

> The Agent mode optimizes Prometheus for the remote write use case. It disables querying, alerting, and local storage, and replaces it with a customized TSDB WAL.

For your specific use case, a whole explaination of InfluxDB's retention policy is out of scope on Stackoverflow. Please refer to the official documentation and [ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you are blocked; please also be aware there is a [stackoverflow of dba](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) where your question may meet a better audience.

Comment: Thank you, Your first sentence was very useful to me. I ask this question because I have observed that influxDB's hard drive usage is larger than I expected, and the official prometheus documentation does not state the effect scope of the parameter. I never notice prometheus agent mode. I'm still using federation, and I'll take a closer look at this blog post

Answer (score 1):

Prometheus has no config options, which can influence retention at remote storage side. It just writes the collected samples to remote storage. The remote storage may provide the ability to configure retention for the data received from Prometheus.

I wouldn't recommend using InfluxDB as a remote storage for Prometheus, since it usually needs bigger amounts of RAM and disk space than the original Prometheus for the same amounts of data. Additionally, InfluxDB doesn't support PromQL (Prometheus query language), so you need to use Flux or InfluxQL for querying the data received from Prometheus. Both Flux and InfluxQL can be non-trivial to use comparing to PromQL - see [this article](https://valyala.medium.com/promql-tutorial-for-beginners-9ab455142085) for details.

There are other remote storage solutions for Prometheus, which need lower amounts of resources than InfluxDB and which natively support PromQL. For example, Cortex (it is renamed to Mimir recently) or VictoriaMetrics (I work on VictoriaMetrics). See, for example, [how to configure VictoriaMetrics remote storage for Prometheus](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/#prometheus-setup).

Comment: Mimir is rather a rewrite/fork of cortex. The performances and the resource requirements are not the same.

Comment: Agreed. Cortex was developed primarily by Grafana labs folks. Now they mostly concentrate on Cortex fork - [Mimir](https://github.com/grafana/mimir), while activity at [Cortex repository](https://github.com/cortexproject/cortex) dropped significantly.

Comment: If I use a remote storage(such as Mimir or VictoriaMetrics), which datasource should I select at grafana datasource configuration? Promtheus or remote storage? Which choice makes the most sense?

Comment: You should select the remote storage datasource in most cases (it is usually Prometheus-compatible). See, for example, [how to configure Grafana for reading data from VictoriaMetrics](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/#grafana-setup).