# Prometheus agent mode feature

Tags: prometheus

I want to try prometheus `agent` mode in my k8s cluster. Use remote write function to send all metrics to a central prometheus in devops role k8s cluster.

Unfortunately there is no official documentation other than this [blog](https://prometheus.io/blog/2021/11/16/agent/) post.

From `feature_flags` [document](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/feature_flags/#prometheus-agent):

```
When enabled, Prometheus runs in agent mode. The agent mode is limited to discovery, scrape and remote write.
```

And from the blog, it is looks like agent mode is used for eage clusters or IOT.

So my questions are as follows:

1. Does Prometheus agent mode able to use Recording rules? (I guess not)
2. Does `prometheus-adapter` work with prometheus agent mode? (I guess not)

Comment: My question was inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72778800/7103358)